# Displaying the ssh hops

Tags: ssh

I have three machines A,B,C. If I ssh into B from A, then into C from B, how can I find the path A->B->C ?

I'd like to display this information in the prompt in order to know where I'm going to land when I exit ssh .

Answer (score 0):

You can look at ssh connections with `lsof` and try to figure out where are you connected from right now.

For example:

```
lsof -i:ssh
root@prmox01:~# lsof -i:ssh
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd     1404 root    3u  IPv4   9601      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd     1404 root    4u  IPv6   9603      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    66653 root    3r  IPv4 167143      0t0  TCP prmox01.example.ru:ssh->192.168.25.178:43406 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: This would work if I could set a remote variable when I ssh into the machine, otherwise I will only get the last hop of the path, but I want the whole path (A->B->C)